# Apache: Can't reroute URL from "file.123.ext" to "file.ext" using mod_rewrite in htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to implement cache busting, as prescribed by: http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/cachebusting/

However when I add the following to the .htaccess file in my media folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and then I try to access a style sheet at: "/media/css/styles.1234.css", Apache complains with:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /media/css/styles.1234.css was not found on this server.
```

I can access styles.css at "/media/css/styles.css" so it's there and it works. I also know that the htaccess file gets processed because we also disallow directories from being browsed in the media folder with "Options -Indexes". Here is the htaccess file in its entirety:

```
Options -Indexes
AllowOverride All

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also mod_rewrite has been confirmed to be loaded with this command: 'a2enmod rewrite'. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to my problem... Even though mod_rewrite was loaded, it needed to be set to on. So I just aded "RewriteEngine On"... resulting htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative path rewrite, missing `RewriteBase`: fail!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, improperly used `Header set X-Frame-Options "DENY"`. Quick fix might be to temporarily comment this out. Hope that help someone who need effective solution 'for now'.